# Error trying to use a function to make cressman interpolation

Tags: r

I am trying to use this function

```
 cressman.interp <- function(locations, values, newdata, nmin, nmax, spheric){
    nGrd <- nrow(newdata)
    outM <- matrix(double(1), nrow = nGrd, ncol = 3)
    nStn <- length(values)
    out <- .Fortran("cressman_interp", locations, as.double(values),
                    as.integer(nStn), newdata, as.integer(nGrd),
                    as.integer(nmin), as.integer(nmax), as.integer(spheric),
                    outM = outM)
    out$outM
}
```

that I get from here https://rdrr.io/github/rijaf-iri/CDTMergingF/src/R/cdtInterpolation_functions.R

but I get this error:
*Error in .Fortran("cressman_interp", locations, as.double(values), as.integer(nStn),  :
Fortran symbol name "cressman_interp" not in load table*

Does someone know how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: The `CDTMergingF` package has some compiled Fortran code that it calls using `.Fortran("cressman_interp"...` . If you don't have this package installed and loaded, that Fortran routine cannot be called from R. Why not just install the package?